# iOS WKWebView - Can't add outlet, only action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I have a simple webview with a back button.
I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQmZSKxOYvs) video.

At 2:05 he switches to the assistance view and control drags the buttons to the code to create outlets.

However, if I try it then it says "insert action" and this code is generated:

```
@IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
}
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong, I followed his steps.

Comment: The popup in your photo, are you trying to out let the `Exit` object instead of the `back button` ?

Comment: No, I try to outlet the back button, I don't know why Exit appears in the popup, makes no sense to me

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach:

1. Declare a button variable in your view controller:

`@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!`

2. In your storyboard, choose the button and then show the **Connections inspector**
3. Drag the **New referencing Outlet** to your view controller (containing the yellow icon)

   - Drag this:

[image]

- To this

[image]

4. Click `myButton`

This way, you have connected the `myButton` variable to the `UIButton` in the storyboard.

Comment: If I drag from "New Referencing Outlet" to "View Controller" then a tiny popup shows where I can select "view".

Comment: Have you clicked Cmd-S to save the changes you've made in your view controller file ? Or just click Cmd-B to build (this will save your changes and then build the project)

Comment: Yes makes no difference

Comment: Have you connected the `webview` successfully ? Or this is the same issue for all the other views ?

Comment: I can't drag the webview to the code, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Change the connection to Outlet instead of Action on that popup

Comment: It is grayed out

Comment: oh! bad, not clear why it is so. can you share a sample project ?

Answer (score 0):

In video, object is ViewController and your is Exit.Use object as ViewController

Right click on ViewController Object and press control drag instance of your back button .

[image]

Comment: I don't understand? Which video

Comment: Youtube tutorial video

Answer (score -1):

To anyone searching for the solution to this problem:

In my case i didn't associate properly the ViewController in the storyboard with my custom ViewController class.

Hope this can help somebody.